# How do I get Hamlet, Prince of Denmark to join my ship?

Tags: star-trek-online

In the Star Trek: Online wiki, there is an entry for [Hamlet, Prince of Denmark](http://www.stowiki.org/Hamlet,_Prince_of_Denmark) it says that it is earned from a mission, but that that mission requires an item, that is retrieved from [a box](http://www.stowiki.org/Holonovel_Storage_Device) but I can't find anywhere in the wiki where I can earn that box. I've tried Performing the [Holodek Performance of Hamlet](http://www.stowiki.org/Assignment:_Holodeck_Performance_of_Hamlet), a dozen or so times, with various outcomes, (critting earned [William Shakespeare](http://www.stowiki.org/William_Shakespeare)), but never anything that leads me to believe I'm on the right track for Hamlet. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hunting around the Star Trek Online wiki, the only way it seems possible to get the Holonovel Storage Device is through random chance from the [Ferengi Lock Box](http://www.stowiki.org/Ferengi_Lock_Box), or the [Gold Ferengi Lock Box](http://www.stowiki.org/Ferengi_Lock_Box_-_Gold).  Seeing as how these require a [Master Key](http://www.stowiki.org/Master_Key), the idea is that you will spend actual money.

However, it seems that it's possible to buy these off of the Exchange for roughly 750,000.  Depending on your circumstances, that may be a better deal.

Keep in mind, though that this box is consumed upon use; you may be spending lots of cash or energy credits to acquire this duty officer.

Comment: Only available through expensive means? That's dumb. Thanks for the info.